# RUNAS ERROR: 1327: Logon failure: user account restriction

Tags: mysql, windows, cmd, runas

I am trying start a service (MySQL80) [= localhost MySQL server] using a cmd command in C++.

My C++ code looks like this (Microsoft Visual Studio 2017)

`system("runas /noprofile /user:Administrator \"NET start MySQL80\"");`

I can then insert the correct admin password. However I get the following error:

```
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run -NET start MySQL80 
1327:Logon failure: user account restriction. Possible reasons are blank passwords not allowed,
logon hour restrictions, or a policy restriction has been enforced.
```

Note that my admin password is not a blank password.

I truly hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Addition: running with "/user: domain\Administrator" or with "/env" does not affect the result.

Comment: First things first, can you run in in a normal shell using `runas`?

Comment: It was my understanding from the usage information of the `RunAs` command, _(`runas /?`)_, that the user account name format should be `<User>@<Domain>`, or `<Domain>\<UserAccountName>`. You have used only `Administrator`, which does not follow either of those naming formats. Additionally you may find that the `/env` option is necessary.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I should've added it. But no. normal shell gives the same error

Comment: @Compo running with the /env option doesn't make any difference, adding the domain name doesn't either.